# How can I return results from a self-join query only for the date I enter?

Tags: mysql, self-join

I need a cohort of active users. 1 day / 7 day / 14 day / 28 day. Same as Google Analytics. I can't seem to wrap my head around the query needed.

I know I need to do a self-join, but that's pretty much as far as I can come.

I've got this query, but it yields a wrong result.

```sql
SELECT
    DATE(logins.logged_in_at) AS `date`,
    logins.company_id,
    SUM(IF(d1.logged_in_at, 1, 0)) AS d1,
    SUM(IF(d7.logged_in_at, 1, 0)) AS d7,
    SUM(IF(d14.logged_in_at, 1, 0)) AS d14,
    SUM(IF(d28.logged_in_at, 1, 0)) AS d28
FROM logins
LEFT JOIN logins AS d1
    ON DATE(logins.logged_in_at) = (DATE(d1.logged_in_at) - INTERVAL 1 DAY)
LEFT JOIN logins AS d7
    ON DATE(logins.logged_in_at) = (DATE(d7.logged_in_at) - INTERVAL 7 DAY)
LEFT JOIN logins AS d14
    ON DATE(logins.logged_in_at) = (DATE(d14.logged_in_at) - INTERVAL 14 DAY)
LEFT JOIN logins AS d28
    ON DATE(logins.logged_in_at) = (DATE(d28.logged_in_at) - INTERVAL 28 DAY)
GROUP BY
    DATE(logins.logged_in_at),
    logins.company_id
ORDER BY
    logins.logged_in_at;
```

```
+------------+------------+----+----+-----+-----+
|    date    | company_id | d1 | d7 | d14 | d28 |
+------------+------------+----+----+-----+-----+
| 2019-01-01 |          1 |  8 |  8 |   8 |   8 |
| 2019-01-02 |          1 |  2 |  2 |   2 |   0 |
| 2019-01-03 |          1 |  2 |  2 |   2 |   0 |
| 2019-01-04 |          1 |  2 |  2 |   2 |   0 |
| 2019-01-05 |          1 |  2 |  2 |   2 |   0 |
| 2019-01-06 |          1 |  2 |  2 |   2 |   0 |
| 2019-01-07 |          1 |  6 |  6 |   6 |   0 |
| 2019-01-08 |          1 |  6 |  6 |   6 |   0 |
| 2019-01-09 |          1 |  6 |  6 |   6 |   0 |
| 2019-01-10 |          1 |  6 |  6 |   6 |   0 |
| 2019-01-11 |          1 |  6 |  6 |   6 |   0 |
| 2019-01-12 |          1 |  6 |  6 |   6 |   0 |
| 2019-01-13 |          1 | 12 | 12 |  12 |   0 |
| 2019-01-14 |          1 | 48 | 48 |  48 |   0 |
| 2019-01-15 |          1 | 48 | 48 |  48 |   0 |
| 2019-01-16 |          1 | 12 | 12 |   0 |   0 |
| 2019-01-17 |          1 | 12 | 12 |   0 |   0 |
| 2019-01-18 |          1 | 12 | 12 |   0 |   0 |
| 2019-01-19 |          1 | 12 | 12 |   0 |   0 |
| 2019-01-20 |          1 | 18 | 18 |   0 |   0 |
| 2019-01-21 |          1 | 36 | 36 |   0 |   0 |
| 2019-01-22 |          1 | 36 | 36 |   0 |   0 |
| 2019-01-23 |          1 |  9 |  0 |   0 |   0 |
| 2019-01-24 |          1 |  9 |  0 |   0 |   0 |
| 2019-01-25 |          1 |  9 |  0 |   0 |   0 |
| 2019-01-26 |          1 |  9 |  0 |   0 |   0 |
| 2019-01-27 |          1 | 12 |  0 |   0 |   0 |
| 2019-01-28 |          1 | 16 |  0 |   0 |   0 |
| 2019-01-29 |          1 |  0 |  0 |   0 |   0 |
+------------+------------+----+----+-----+-----+
```

Table structure and sample data as follows:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `logins` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `company_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `logged_in_at` timestamp NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `logins_company_id_index` (`company_id`),
  KEY `logins_user_id_index` (`user_id`),
  KEY `logins_logged_in_at_index` (`logged_in_at`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=57 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `logins` (`id`, `company_id`, `user_id`, `logged_in_at`)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 1, '2019-01-01 00:00:00'),
    (2, 1, 1, '2019-01-02 00:00:00'),
    (3, 1, 1, '2019-01-03 00:00:00'),
    (4, 1, 1, '2019-01-04 00:00:00'),
    (5, 1, 1, '2019-01-05 00:00:00'),
    (6, 1, 1, '2019-01-06 00:00:00'),
    (7, 1, 1, '2019-01-07 00:00:00'),
    (8, 1, 1, '2019-01-08 00:00:00'),
    (9, 1, 1, '2019-01-09 00:00:00'),
    (10, 1, 1, '2019-01-10 00:00:00'),
    (11, 1, 1, '2019-01-11 00:00:00'),
    (12, 1, 1, '2019-01-12 00:00:00'),
    (13, 1, 1, '2019-01-13 00:00:00'),
    (14, 1, 1, '2019-01-14 00:00:00'),
    (15, 1, 1, '2019-01-15 00:00:00'),
    (16, 1, 1, '2019-01-16 00:00:00'),
    (17, 1, 1, '2019-01-17 00:00:00'),
    (18, 1, 1, '2019-01-18 00:00:00'),
    (19, 1, 1, '2019-01-19 00:00:00'),
    (20, 1, 1, '2019-01-20 00:00:00'),
    (21, 1, 1, '2019-01-21 00:00:00'),
    (22, 1, 1, '2019-01-22 00:00:00'),
    (23, 1, 1, '2019-01-23 00:00:00'),
    (24, 1, 1, '2019-01-24 00:00:00'),
    (25, 1, 1, '2019-01-25 00:00:00'),
    (26, 1, 1, '2019-01-26 00:00:00'),
    (27, 1, 1, '2019-01-27 00:00:00'),
    (28, 1, 1, '2019-01-28 00:00:00'),
    (29, 1, 1, '2019-01-29 00:00:00'),
    (30, 1, 2, '2019-01-14 00:00:00'),
    (31, 1, 2, '2019-01-15 00:00:00'),
    (32, 1, 2, '2019-01-16 00:00:00'),
    (33, 1, 2, '2019-01-17 00:00:00'),
    (34, 1, 2, '2019-01-18 00:00:00'),
    (35, 1, 2, '2019-01-19 00:00:00'),
    (36, 1, 2, '2019-01-20 00:00:00'),
    (37, 1, 2, '2019-01-21 00:00:00'),
    (38, 1, 2, '2019-01-22 00:00:00'),
    (39, 1, 2, '2019-01-23 00:00:00'),
    (40, 1, 2, '2019-01-24 00:00:00'),
    (41, 1, 2, '2019-01-25 00:00:00'),
    (42, 1, 2, '2019-01-26 00:00:00'),
    (43, 1, 2, '2019-01-27 00:00:00'),
    (44, 1, 2, '2019-01-28 00:00:00'),
    (45, 1, 2, '2019-01-29 00:00:00'),
    (46, 1, 3, '2019-01-21 00:00:00'),
    (47, 1, 3, '2019-01-22 00:00:00'),
    (48, 1, 3, '2019-01-23 00:00:00'),
    (49, 1, 3, '2019-01-24 00:00:00'),
    (50, 1, 3, '2019-01-25 00:00:00'),
    (51, 1, 3, '2019-01-26 00:00:00'),
    (52, 1, 3, '2019-01-27 00:00:00'),
    (53, 1, 3, '2019-01-28 00:00:00'),
    (54, 1, 3, '2019-01-29 00:00:00'),
    (55, 1, 4, '2019-01-28 00:00:00'),
    (56, 1, 4, '2019-01-29 00:00:00');
```

If I ran the query needed on `2019-01-29`, I would expect to get something like this :

```
+------------+------------+----+----+-----+-----+
| company_id |    date    | d1 | d7 | d14 | d28 |
+------------+------------+----+----+-----+-----+
|          1 | 2019-01-29 |  4 |  3 |   2 |   1 |
+------------+------------+----+----+-----+-----+
```

Please let me know if you need more information

Comment: Pro tip: we're a bit different on Stack Overflow from other sources of help on the internet. 
Beginners are welcome, but we expect a certain amount of effort to be expended on a question prior to a question being posted. 
We dont write code for you although we are very willing to help you fix issues with code you have written.

Comment: I'm sorry @RiggsFolly, didn't mean to come of as you guys were supposed to do my job. Added my own progress, but this was most for getting points on _where_ to look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only because this query generates the same result , I assume it's what you're after...

```
SELECT company_id
     , date
     , SUM(d1) d1
     , SUM(d7) d7
     , SUM(d14) d14
     , SUM(d28) d28
  FROM 
     ( SELECT DISTINCT x.logged_in_at date
                     , x.company_id
                     , y.user_id
                     , y.logged_in_at = x.logged_in_at - INTERVAL   1 DAY d1 
                     , y.logged_in_at = x.logged_in_at - INTERVAL   7 DAY d7
                     , y.logged_in_at = x.logged_in_at - INTERVAL  14 DAY d14 
                     , y.logged_in_at = x.logged_in_at - INTERVAL  28 DAY d28 

                  FROM logins x 
                  JOIN logins y 
                    ON y.company_id = x.company_id
                   AND y.logged_in_at < x.logged_in_at 
                 WHERE x.logged_in_at = '2019-01-29'
     ) a
 GROUP
    BY company_id
     , date;
```

Answer (score 0):

The following query should do the trick. The inner query assigns a bucket to each record in the table, the outer query does the aggregation.

```
SELECT 
    company_id,
    @ref_date,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN bucket = 'd1' THEN user_id END) d1,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN bucket = 'd7' THEN user_id END) d7,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN bucket = 'd14' THEN user_id END) d14,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN bucket = 'd28' THEN user_id END) d28 
FROM (
    SELECT l.*,
    CASE 
        WHEN l.logged_in_at >= @ref_date - INTERVAL 1 DAY THEN 'd1' 
        WHEN l.logged_in_at >= @ref_date - INTERVAL 8 DAY THEN 'd7'
        WHEN l.logged_in_at >= @ref_date - INTERVAL 15 DAY THEN 'd14' 
        WHEN l.logged_in_at >= @ref_date - INTERVAL 29 DAY THEN 'd28' 
    END bucket
    FROM logins l
    WHERE l.logged_in_at < @ref_date
) x
GROUP BY company_id
```

With your sample data **[in this db fiddle demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/914BX6ezka1YqEcDp8AMi1/0)**, this returns :

```
| company_id | @ref_date  | d1  | d7  | d14 | d28 |
| ---------- | ---------- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1          | 2019-01-29 | 4   | 3   | 2   | 1   |
```